# Disable auto creation of service definition in Lumen/Laravel

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, ioc-container, lumen

I'm registering a service in Lumen, when I put a typo into the definition then the all usages are switching to auto-magically created service definition on-fly.

How to disable such automatic generation behavior? 
So the Lumen could tell me "hey, you are trying to access not registered service" instead of magically creating it for me so I could ask my self what the hell is going on?

Thanks :)

Comment: I did not quite understand what you mean. Lumen does not "magically" create services that have never been bound in the IoC container. Lumen only serves you already bounded instances in the IoC.

Comment: It's when you access the service by the class name, then if there is no definition its creating a new definition basing on the constructor of the class.
But I just stared using the convention of dots in the naming like in Symfony.
Funny thing is that the container is not validating so much and for example throwing an ReflectionException if the service was not defined.